# How can we examine the value through debugger, for implicitly defined constructor/Destructor ?

Tags: c++

How can we examine the value through debugger, for implicitly defined constructor/Destructor ?

```
class base
{
 int a;
 public:
};

int main() 
{
 base b;
 return 0;
}
```

Here since i have not provided any constructor/destructor, it should be implicitly provided(declare and defined) by the compiler(as per book). How i can verify this using debugger.
I tried to put some breakpoints but not fully understood how it works.

Comment: It depends on whether the debugger allows putting breakpoints in the implicitly-defined members. But you don't have to verify their existence - they're guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Of course, in this case, the destructor may be "nothing" - it still conceptually exists, but since it contains no actual code, it can be inlined and removed completely by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the implicit constructor has to do in your sample code?
According to gdb, the function `base::base()` is not defined in the object code my g++ 4.7.3 produced:

```
(gdb) b base::base()
Function "base::base()" not defined.
```

Just a simple task for that constructor, such as being there for a derived class need of calling it, would make it necessary for the compiler to synthesize it:

```
class base
{
 int a;
 public:
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
  derived() {};
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the `base::base()` function can be debugged:

```
(gdb) b base::base() 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400516: file test_impl_ctr.cpp, line 1.
```

Of course, there's little to discover in an empty implementation of a constructor (in this case), but the curiosity is satisfied :)!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the constructor - your *class* `base` isn't even guaranteed to exist in any meaningful form after your program is compiled.  In fact, an optimizing compiler would probably remove it entirely and just allocate stack-space for `int base::a`.

Classes, constructors, destructors, functions, etc. are conceptual abstractions that exist as C++ programming concepts, and are guaranteed by the standard to produce certain behaviors.  Once you compile your program and you're examining the assembly instructions, you won't necessarily find any correspondence between the actual machine instructions and C++ programming-concepts/abstractions.

So, since your implicitly defined constructor doesn't actually do anything, the compiler isn't obligated to generate any actual code for it.  It still exists, conceptually, as a C++ concept, but it's not necessarily realized by any actual machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming visual studio, you can view the generated assembly code by placing a breakpoint in the line you declare `b`, let it hit the breakpoint, and press Alt+8. However, the default constructor/destructor does no work other than call constructors/destructors of every member, which would be empty in your case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard a C++ compiler is expected to behave *as if* it did all the things that are explained in your book. However if these things have no visible behaviour, as for instance emitting some output, it is free to skip them.

As the program in your example doesn't contain any code that has visible effects, the compiler is likely to produce an executable that doesn't do anything.